Is there any way to change Roku Poster's rotation?
I am creating a roku channel. I need to display images in slide mode. The problem is, some images are in horizontal, some are in vertical mode. So, I need to rotate Poster node according to images type. And I am wondering if is there any way to rotate whole screen, not just Poster node.
Example of horizontal img
Example of vertical img
This is my xml code right now.
<component name="PlaylistRendererScreen"
           extends="Scene">
    <script type="text/brightscript"
            uri="PlaylistRendererScreen.bs" />
    <children>
        <Poster id="testPoster"
                width="1920"
                height="1080"
                loadWidth="1920"
                loadHeight="1080"
                translation="[0,0]"
                visible="true" />
    </children>
</component>

And this is my bs file:
sub init()
    m.poster = m.top.findNode("testPoster")

    m.mediaList = [
        { type: "image", url: "url" },
        { type: "image", url: "url" },
        { type: "image", url: "url" },
        { type: "image", url: "url" },
    ]

    m.currentIndex = 0
    m.interval = 5000   ' Interval for switching (5 seconds)

    startSlideShowTimer()
    showMedia()
end sub

sub startSlideShowTimer()
    if (m.timer = invalid)
        m.timer = createObject("roSGNode", "Timer")
        m.timer.duration = m.interval / 1000
        m.timer.repeat = true
        m.timer.observeField("fire", "onTimerFired")
        m.top.appendChild(m.timer)
    end if
    m.timer.control = "start"  ' Start the timer
end sub

sub onTimerFired()
    m.currentIndex = (m.currentIndex + 1) mod m.mediaList.count()
    showMedia()
end sub

sub showMedia()
    mediaItem = m.mediaList[m.currentIndex]
    mediaType = mediaItem.type
    mediaUrl = mediaItem.url

    if (mediaType = "image")
        displayImage(mediaUrl)
    else if (mediaType = "video")
        ' Create video display here.
    end if
end sub

sub displayImage(url as string)
    if (m.poster <> invalid)
        m.poster.uri = url
        m.poster.visible = true
    else
        print "Error: Poster node not found."
    end if

    startSlideShowTimer()
end sub

I tried to add rotation into Poster node. But it didn't work. Actually, I couldn't even see the images. I also tried to add Group node and Poster in that Group node. Then I added rotation in Group, I managed to see images but not in correct rotation.

Poster is a subclass of Group node, which has rotation field. You don't need extra Group

Thank you for your answer. But how can I rotate Poster? When I add rotation to Poster, it doesn't display image at all. And like I explained, I will have both horizontal and vertical images. So, I need to change orientation of Poster 0, 90, 180, 270. And image quality shouldn't change.

btw .rotation should be in radians, i.e. -degrees/180*pi so -pi/2 = -1.57 for a clockwise 90 degrees
